# How to gradually hide a UIImageView beneath a UIView (which is transparent)?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have an `UIImageView` with red color for background. I also have a transparent `UIView` located above the image view. This image view moves upwards. How can I gradually hide the image view as it would go beneath a transparent view but still showing what is beneath the transparent `UIView`?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: My code is more complex than what I can show but I hope my description is suggestive enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your image view into **another view** and set `clipsToBounds` to `YES`. Then set frame of the new view to desired rectangle where you want the image view to be cliped. Then, when you move the image view outside of this rectangle, it will be cut off.